# Grails how direct multiple actions to the same view?

Tags: grails

I have the following navigation setup on a grails controller is it possible for List_X and List_Y to go to different actions but then be mapped to the same gsp file?

```
subItems: [ 
    [ action: 'list_X',title: 'Something', order:1 ],                                                           
    [ action: 'error_X',title: 'Something',order:2 ],
    [ action: 'list_Y', title: 'Something', order:3 ],
    [ action: 'error_Y',title: 'Something', order:4 ],
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify manually which gsp file should be rendered. In action in your controller do this:

```
def list_X() {
    // ... some code
    render(view : "listView", model : [name : "bob", items : []])
}

def list_Y() {
    //... some code
    render(view : "listView", model : [name : "bob", items : []])
}
```

That way, same gsp template will be used to render result of both actions.